# Babel doesn't transpile class extending correctly

Tags: javascript, babeljs, webpack-4

Consider the code below

```
class Test1 {
    emit() {
        console.log(2)
    }
}

class Test extends Test1 {
    test() {
        console.log(1);
    }
}

const a = new Test();
a.test()
```

Babel transpiles this code into [this](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20firefox%2043&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBGaBvAUASHgWwEskAKASg02ium2AHsA7COkeAOhDoHNiAmUytQC-mEaEgwEyaPAAeSeAwAmkxKgpUFyMhur0mLdpx4pSAbkEiRmfdLDQAvNAbwA7nDVkLYNlpKkgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=Node-16.13&version=7.18.13&externalPlugins=&assumptions=%7B%7D)

This works perfectly on modern browsers, but it doesn't work on Firefox 43

```
TypeError: a.test is not a function
```

What I realized:

1. Babel transpiles class extending into Reflect.construct (If the platform has Reflect support) or context binding
2. Reflect.construct(Super, arguments, NewTarget) on Firefox 43 skips prototypes from NewTarget
3. We can represent this class extending using Reflect.construct in the following form:

```
const test = {};
test.__proto__ = {
    test() {
        console.log(1);
    },
};

function Super() {
    this.emit = function () {
        console.log(2);
    };
}

function Target() {}

Target.prototype = test.__proto__;
const result = Reflect.construct(Super, [test], Target);
result.test();
```

Also, I found the code in [closure compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/2725a4f3b73d1536a9795424ae56bea07c949dd3/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/js/es6/util/construct.js) which declares "brokenConstruct".
It refers to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/ChakraCore/issues/3217)

What am I doing wrong? What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Why are you testing on a browser that's 62 versions out-of-date? It's also 7 years old now and probably shouldn't be used

Comment: Because some users use both IE and old firefox

Answer (score 0):

I realized that It is firefox bug
There are comments from core-js/modules/es.reflect.construct polyfill

```
// `Reflect.construct` method
// https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-reflect.construct
// MS Edge supports only 2 arguments and argumentsList argument is optional
// FF Nightly sets third argument as `new.target`, but does not create `this` from it
```